# Arbitrary elements in a quotient ring $\Bbb R[x]/(x-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If I have an ideal $(x-1)$ for the ring $\Bbb R[x]$, how do I think of the quotient ring $\Bbb R[x]/(x-1)$? I have all polynomials with:

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 {\pmod {x-1}}$$
How do I think of the Simple ring generated by this? What is an arbitrary element in this quotient ring?

Comment: It looks like the polynomial evaluated at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

When you quotient by $x-1$ you are saying that $x-1 \equiv 0$ (or $x \equiv 1)$. With this in mind 
\begin{align*}
a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dotsb +a_1x+a_0 & \equiv a_n(1)^n+a_{n-1}(1)^{n-1}+ \dotsb + a_1(1)+a_0 \pmod{x-1}\\
& \equiv a_n+a_{n-1}+ \dotsb + a_1+a_0 \pmod{x-1}\\
\end{align*}
Thus every polynomial is equivalent to its value at $x=1$. Thus 
$$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle \cong \mathbb{R}$$
and the cosets would look like
$$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle = \{r+\langle x-1\rangle \, | \, r \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: Ahhh of course, thank you, I am not thinking clearly apparently